# Do we have access PG&E case files?

Tags: california, legal-research

Is there any way to have access to PG&E cases in the recent bankruptcy court? Are they public?

Answer (score 1):

The files are a matter of public record and are available on PACER if you have the case number. Some information is protected and only available to parties (e.g. unredacted copies of exhibits containing account numbers, or social security numbers).

Comment: now how to get the case number? ;)

Answer (score 1):

While PACER needs a case number, I could find the case number via Google by googling `PG&E Bankruptcy PACER`, resulting in the result of the [US Bankruptcy Court, Northern District of California](https://www.canb.uscourts.gov/case-info/pge-corporation-and-pacific-gas-and-electric-company), telling the case number is 19-30088-DM, jointly administered with 1930089-DM under the Honorable Dennis Montali.

Next stage would be to go to [PACER](https://pacer.uscourts.gov/), where you'll need to log in and then enter the case number. Note that PACER does bill you by the documents accessed.

As an alternative source, the docket of close to [12 000 filings (in Feb 2022)](https://restructuring.primeclerk.com/pge/Home-DocketInfo) can be found on the website of Kroll, who handle this bankruptcy case.